# Connect to in-process DynamoDBLocal via Amazonica or Cognitect AWS API?

Tags: java, clojure, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk, amazonica

**Current situation:**

Clojure code -> Amazonica -> AWS Java SDK -> Standalone DynamoDBLocal.jar in background process over HTTP.

**Desired situation:**

Clojure code -> Amazonica -> AWS Java SDK -> In-process DynamoDB local

I managed to get the in-process DynamoDB to work, I can list tables (see below) but I don't know how to connect to it.

I tried looking at the AWS Java SDK docs and samples. Crickets.

The Amazonica [docs](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica#dynamodbv2) shows only the `:endpoint "http://localhost:8000"` option (I'm using it currently).

[Cognitect's AWS API](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api#endpoint-override) also seems to support only the HTTP version via :endpoint-override.

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?

Here's the code I've got so far:

```clj
(import '(com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.embedded DynamoDBEmbedded))
(.. DynamoDBEmbedded create amazonDynamoDB listTables)
=> #object[com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ListTablesResult 
   0x712e68f7 "{TableNames: [],}"]
```

Apart from the dependency itself I had to add the following to the alias in deps.edn

`:jvm-opts ["-Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib"]`

where DynamoDBLocal_lib contains the native libraries: libsqlite4java-osx.dylib / libsqlite4java-linux-amd64.so / sqlite4java-win32-x64.dll

P.S. I don't want to use Docker

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `DynamoDBEmbedded`?

```java
AmazonDynamoDB dynamodb = DynamoDBEmbedded.create().amazonDynamoDB();

for(String table : dynamodb.listTables().getTableNames()) {
    System.out.println(table);
}

dynamodb.shutdown();
```

You can find a fool code listing [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/DynamoDBLocalFixture.java), in `aws-dynamodb-examples` repo on GitHub. And [here](http://softwarebyjosh.com/2018/03/25/how-to-unit-test-your-dynamodb-queries.html) is another blog post with code samples.

Comment: Thanks! I did indeed try DynamoDBEmbedded and it works! My problem is how to make AWS Java SDK (or it's wrapper Amazonica) use that instead of the standalone one.